# JavaScript Numer-to-String conversion performance

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on SVG animations, which require me to convert arrays of 3D vectors to SVG path attributes. Right now, it seems like the bottleneck is the actual conversion between strings and numbers. (Not the more complex matrix transformations and calls to Math.sin/cos/exp!)

Here is a screenshot from the Chrome profiler:
[image]

What's the best way to speed this up, if performance is critical? Using `` `${posn.x * p},${posn.y * p}` `` has slightly worse performance, and using `.toString()` or `.toFixed(2)` was MUCH worse.

Comment: Just as a mention, a `Math.sin` call is probably mostly a table lookup, plus very limited linear interpolation steps. I wouldn't be confused, if converting a number to decimal is just naturally more problematic. It should still be extremely fast though, you must be doing a LOT of these, to run into problems. I'd think about, whether there isn't something more fundamental, that can be changed about this approach you are taking. It's often better, to avoid getting conceptually close to a performance limit - the attention you'll have to spend for optimizations is very costly.

Comment: It's quite a complex scene, so probably around 5000 points on every frame. It feels very strange to convert numbers to strings and set them as a "d" attribute for the path, just for the browser to have to parse this string again in reverse. However, I don't think SVG elements have an API for doing this directly :(

Comment: If you concatenate these results afterwards then don't do it here. Instead push the elements individually in the accumulator array, and in the end do array.join('').